# After git filter-branch, running it again gives HEAD: no such file in working tree

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm running the following commands in succession:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter codefolder -- master
```

And then trying to run the following command so that the previous folder structure is preserved after subdirectory-filter:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter \                'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&codefolder/-" |                        GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \                                git update-index --index-info &&
         mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

However on the second command, I get the following error:

fatal: HEAD: no such path in the working tree.
Use 'git  -- ...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.

I tried to see whether HEAD is set:
cat .git/HEAD gives  refs/heads/master

Tried to set GIT_INDEX_FILE myself:
GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/index

But re-running the second command after these changes, it is still not passing.

Any idea how to fix this? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Azure VM.

Comment: pop a `pwd` in there somewhere to see where your filter's getting run. Relative paths might be a little out of place there.  edit: also, you've got escape problems, I'm pretty sure the `\t` will get passed to sed as a `t`.  dropping `echo` or even `printf %s\\n` in front of the commands is another handy trick

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting your command for sane whitespace shows the problems:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter '
        git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&codefolder/-" \
        | GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info &&
         mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
    ' HEAD
```

You're passing `HEAD` as a loose argument, and filter-branch isn't responding very well.  Either pass `-- HEAD` (see the docs, everything after a `--` is for rev-list) or just leave it off as filter-branch defaults to supplying that for rev-list that anyway.

Also as mentioned in comments, the shell doesn't do C escapes in double-quoted strings, the backslash is just a shoehorn. The easy fix is to double the escape before the `t` so `sed` sees `\t` and does its own more C-ish escape processing.